# R -raster: Define raster extent from centre and rotation

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I am quite new to R spatial transformation. My aim is to write a GeoTiff to be correctly geolocated in GIS software (e.g. ArcGIS).

I have a raster with known coordinates of the centre (proj: UTM WGS84  Zone 30 N; epsg: 32630). To my understanding (but please correct me if not), to display the raster in the correct position I need to define its extent (I know the pixel resolution). My problem is that the raster was originally captured from a UAVs platform so its correct position depend on the yaw angle of UAVs and gimbal at the time of shot.

How can I define correctly raster extension knowing coordinates of the raster centre and its yaw angle?